# Does restricting oneself to a typeface allow that typeface's variants?

Tags: typography, terminology

If I'm limited to only a typeface, can I still use its font variants (like various weights and italics) and have it still be considered only a typeface?

Comment: I edited your question to more concisely describe what you want to know. If I butchered anything beyond recognition, feel free to [edit] it back.

Comment: it's all good now, thanks to you. that's exactly what i wanted to ask.

Answer (score 6):

You could use as many font variants within a typeface as you'd want, but don't go overboard.

It is a great idea to limit yourself to only two typefaces for a project. 'Typeface' is the important term here, as opposed to 'font'.* You are free to use any font variants (weights, italics) within the same typeface and still retain the uniformity that the two-typeface rule was meant to create. Don't use too many different ones, though--dont be tempted to put all 16 weights of Montserrat into your branding project, unless it is a *huge* project and sixteen different use cases are required.

*<sub><sup>A typeface is a collection of fonts. Helvetica is a typeface; Helvetica bold and Helvetica black italic are fonts.</sup></sub>

Comment: Such a kludge (collection of loosely related things) would present a unique appearance but might end up entirely unreadable and if used in a commercial pronounced so differently by announcers that it is unrecognizable. As such, it might become degraded to "that bookstore thing."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, within a type face your only options for directing attention are size, weight, skew and position.

You had better use some stylings to distinguish sections of writing.

This is fundamental to typography.